# Task executor in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, amazon-sqs

In my Spring Boot application I'm listening message queue. When a message appears I need to execute it **synchronously**(one by one) in some task-executor.

I'm using Amazon SQS, this is my config:

```
    /**
     * AWS Credentials Bean
     */
    @Bean
    public AWSCredentials awsCredentials() {
        return new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretAccessKey);
    }

    /**
     * AWS Client Bean
     */
    @Bean
    public AmazonSQS amazonSQSAsyncClient() {
        AmazonSQS sqsClient = new AmazonSQSClient(awsCredentials());
        sqsClient.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1));
        return sqsClient;
    }

    /**
     * AWS Connection Factory
     */
    @Bean
    public SQSConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        SQSConnectionFactory.Builder factoryBuilder = new SQSConnectionFactory.Builder(
                Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1));
        factoryBuilder.setAwsCredentialsProvider(new AWSCredentialsProvider() {

            @Override
            public AWSCredentials getCredentials() {
                return awsCredentials();
            }

            @Override
            public void refresh() {
            }

        });
        return factoryBuilder.build();
    }

    /**
     * Registering QueueListener for queueName
     */
    @Bean
    public DefaultMessageListenerContainer defaultMessageListenerContainer() {
        DefaultMessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
        messageListenerContainer.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        messageListenerContainer.setMessageListener(new MessageListenerAdapter(new QueueListener()));
        messageListenerContainer.setDestinationName(queueName);

        return messageListenerContainer;
    }
```

Also I need to have possibility to check the status of this task-executor, for example - number of scheduled tasks.

Is it a good idea to use Spring `SyncTaskExecutor` for this purpose ? If so, could you please show an example how it can be used with Spring Boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

After revealing your messaging technology and Spring configuration for it, simplest way for you is to configure `SyncTaskExecutor` (or `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)` would do the job also) as executor for your `DefaultMessageListenerContainer`. [Use this method](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer.html#setTaskExecutor%28java.util.concurrent.Executor%29).

You can register Task executor as separate bean (via @Bean annotation) and autowire it to `defaultMessageListenerContainer()` method (just add `TaskExectuor` as parameter).

---

**Below answer is relevant for JMS messaging. It was created before AWS SQS usage was revealed in question:**

You didn't mention which messaging technology are you using, therefore I assume JMS.

If synchronous execution is requirement, I believe you can't use native JMS listeners (need to avoid `SimpleJmsListenerContainerFactory` or `SimleMessageListenerContainer`).

Instead I would suggest to use `@JmsListener` annotation with `DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory` (this uses long polling instead of native JMS listeners) and configure `SyncTaskExecutor` (or `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)` would do the job also) as executor for mentioned container factory: `DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory.setTaskExecutor()`.

[This is simple Spring Boot JMS example with DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory configured](https://github.com/lkrnac/book-eiws-code-samples/tree/master/05-jms/0509-jms-message-converter). You just  need to plug in suitable task executor.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I'm using AWS SQS

Comment: I have added my SQS config into the question